# Adding library project and using it in main project

Tags: android, android-studio

Im trying to include and use https://github.com/edmodo/range-bar project in my app. So I extracted it and added as `Android Project` module to my main project. Then I added some XML of this rangebar to my project.

```
<com.edmodo.rangebar.RangeBar xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/rangebar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

After launching it, it crashes:

```
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.edmodo.rangebar.RangeBar" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.app-1.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app-lib/com.app-1, /vendor/lib, /system/lib]]
```

Do I need to define something somewhere else?

Thanks for help

Comment: you need to reference the library project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first of all, you should include `Range-Bar` as module into your project (if the library provide a jar file, you can add it to your `libs` folder too).

So here are the steps you should do to add the library:

1. **File** -> **New Module** -> **Import Existing Project / Android Library** -> and follow the steps to create the module
2. After adding module successfully right click to your main module and select **Open Module Settings** , select your module (main one) and go to **Dependencies** tab. Click the `+` button below and select **Module Dependencies**. Than it will show you a pop-up with your created module, click on it and select `OK`. Than `Apply` and `OK` again.

And now you should be able to use that library in your project without any errors.

Comment: Perfect explanation! Thank you :)